# VS2017RC Typescript not generating javascript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

In VS 2017 changes to a typescript file no longer result in any javascript being created, despite a message on the lower bar saying "outputs generated successfully".

I've tried on 2 machines with the same version of VS installed and using a simple test project with the same result

- is this a bug?
- has something changed in the way you work with typescript in VS 2017?
- do I need a tsconfig.json file? I have never needed one in the past...

Answer (score 1):

You need an tsconfig.json file for Visual Studio to build ts files into js.